# Can't dispatch action in class component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, dispatch

```
// action
export const getEvents = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: GET_EVENTS_REQUEST })
    const data = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/schedule').then((response) => response.data)
    dispatch({ type: GET_EVENTS_SUCCESS, payload: data })
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: GET_EVENTS_FAIL,
      payload:
      error.response && error.response.data.message
        ? error.response.data.message
        : error.message,
    })
  }
}

// reducer
export const getEventsReducer = (state = { event: [] }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
  case GET_EVENTS_REQUEST:
    return { loading: true }
  case GET_EVENTS_SUCCESS:
    return { loading: false, event: action.payload }
  case GET_EVENTS_FAIL:
    return { loading: false, error: action.payload }
  default:
    return state
  }
}

// and this is how I'm trying to call my action:
import { getEvents } from '../../redux/actions/calendarActions'

class Calendar extends React.PureComponent {
    componentDidMount() {
        const { dispatch } = this.props
        console.log(dispatch(getEvents()))
    }
}
export default connect()(Calendar)
// component is much bigger, I only added relevant parts
```

Up until my reducer, if I console.log my data, it is correct, as well as in my redux dev tools tab: an array with a few entries. But when console.logging in my Calendar component, it returns a promise, with undefined result:

```
Promise {<pending>}
[[Prototype]]: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: undefined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `getEvents` does indeed return `undefined`

Comment: Are you using `redux-thunk` by any chance? If not, you should. It's a middleware that lets you dispatch async actions. Also, you didn't `await` the dispatch, so of course it returns a `Promise`

Comment: This is exactly how redux (and state in general) works. The same way you cannot console log the result of `this.setState`. Instead, the update triggers a re-render where you can get the updated values as props (assuming it is connected correctly).

Comment: @RonB. awaiting `dispatch` is pointless, it doesn't return anything. The promise is because `getEvents` is async.

Comment: @RonB. I am using redux-thunk and added it to my store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you want to have access to either the dispatch or the store of Redux within a component. you already have the dispatch function within the component, but if you need access to Redux state inside it:

first you need to define such function, which makes the redux store available in the component.

```
    const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  state: state // a "state" prop is available in the component which points to redux state, 
})
```

or you can customize it if you only need certain properties of Redux state:

```
        const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  state: state.event // 
})
```

and change the connect function like this:

```
connect(mapStateToProps)(Calendar)
```